# Getting NSOutlineView rows to be editable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

Does anyone here know how to make cells in NSOutlineView's editible? Im using the sampe code from apple and I cant seem to get it work at all.

I am trying to set it up so that when you click twice in rapid succession on a cell in the NSOutlineView, the cell becomes editible so the user can update the text inside the cell. (In the same way as it works in xcode, and mail and so on).

I am including most of the rest of the code of this controller in the vain hope someone can spot what I am doing wrong, this is very frustrating. I know `shouldEditTableColumn` is being called as it is returning the NSLog message upon double click.

```
@implementation DisplayHierarchyController
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // cache the reused icon images
    folderImage = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType:NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(kGenericFolderIcon)] retain];
    [folderImage setSize:NSMakeSize(16,16)];
    objectImage = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType:NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(kGenericPreferencesIcon)] retain];
    [objectImage setSize:NSMakeSize(16,16)];
    diagramImage = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType:NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(kGenericEditionFileIcon)] retain];
    [diagramImage setSize:NSMakeSize(16,16)];
    //
    // Tell the outline view to use a special type of cell
    //NSTableColumn *tableColumn = [[outline tableColumns] objectAtIndex: 0];
    //ImageTextCell *imageTextCell = [[[ImageTextCell alloc] init] autorelease];
    //[imageTextCell setEditable:YES];
    //[tableColumn setDataCell:imageTextCell];
    //
    [[[outline tableColumns] objectAtIndex: 0] setEditable: YES];
}
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    NSLog(@"edit %@", tableColumn);
    return YES;
}
- (NSCell *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    ImageTextCell *imageTextCell = [[[ImageTextCell alloc] init] autorelease];
    [imageTextCell setEditable:YES];
    return imageTextCell;
}
// Returns the object that will be displayed in the tree
- (id)outlineView: (NSOutlineView *)outlineView child: (int)index ofItem: (id)item {
    if(item == nil)
        return [[document children] objectAtIndex: index];
    if([item isKindOfClass: [Item class]])
        return [[item children] objectAtIndex: index];
    return document;
}
- (BOOL)outlineView: (NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable: (id)item {
if([item isKindOfClass: [Item class]])
    return [[item children] count]>0;
return NO;
}
- (int)outlineView: (NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem: (id)item {
    if(item == nil)
        return document.children.count;
    if([item isKindOfClass: [Item class]])
        return [[item children] count];
    return 0;
}
- (id)outlineView: (NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
    if([item isKindOfClass: [Item class]])
        return [item name];
    return @"n/a";
}
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
    NSLog(@"setObjectValue called");
}
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)olv willDisplayCell:(NSCell*)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    [cell setEditable: YES];
    [cell setAllowsEditingTextAttributes: YES];
    [(ImageTextCell*)cell setImage: objectImage];
}
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor {
    if ([[fieldEditor string] length] == 0) {
        // don't allow empty node names
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: “I cant seem to get it work at all.” What do you mean by this? Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Hopefully that makes it clearer. I want double clicking on a row to enable editing of that row

Comment: I am doing more study on how to get this to work, the apple documentation says "An outline view inherits much of its behavior from its parent class, NSTableView......or more information, see Table View Programming Guide." An NSTableView does have this method "(BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex" but I dont seem to be able to add it to my controller in a way that it gets called.

Comment: That's a delegate method, so you would need to be the delegate. Also, you need to implement the NSOutlineView version: `outlineView:shouldEditTableColumn:item:`

Comment: Yep, in my desparateness i've tried both! (:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know this is a very old post, but if any one is experiencing the same issue, this may not be an issue related to code. For my case it was an issue related to do with a value set in the XIB itself.

So lets say you've copied all the Apple code, and you've got your NSOutlineView up and running, and some how its still not editable, go to your XIB and set the following setting of the NSTextField of the cell you want to be editable.  In my case the behavior setting was set to *none* by default. Maybe its the same problem for you

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks!  This was the problem I was having too.  I was so focused on fixing a 'bug' in my code that I didn't think to check IB.

Comment: This is still the case in Xcode8 and Swift 3 with view-based outlineViews where shouldEditTableColumn does not get called. Good catch.

Answer (score 6):

Is the column itself set as editable? Ordinarily, you would do this in IB.

Also, have you implemented [the `outlineView:setObjectValue:` method](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSOutlineViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/outlineView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:byItem:) in your data source?

Comment: When I click through to the cell in interface builder it is set as editible. I am however overriding the cells with the custom cell that has the image, not sure if thats relevant.

I am also not sure what should go in setObjectValue (its not clear from the documentation) :(

Comment: I didn't say the cell, I said the column. It has its own editable checkbox. As for `setObjectValue:`: That's where you take the change the user made and apply it to your model. It's the reverse direction of `objectValue:`, which examines the model and provides that information to the outline view to show to the user.

Comment: Doh, sorry I misread what you wrote. The NSTableColumn is ticked as editible (it seems that would be the default, as I didn't tick it)

Answer (score 2):

Ive just discovered I can "fake it" by altering the `shouldEditTableColumn`. Its really not ideal, but it works. After so many hours trying to get it to work, at least this is something:

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    NSLog(@"edit %@", tableColumn);
    [outline editColumn:0 row:[outline selectedRow] withEvent:[NSApp currentEvent] select:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is not technically the right answer but its the closest thing I could find to get it to work. It doesn't work quite right but its better than nothing thats for sure!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way around this.  Set the data cell for the column in IB (programmatically in awakeFromNib should work too).  I actually use 2 different custom cell classes. My solution:

```
NSCell *cell = [tableColumn dataCellForRow: [outlineView rowForItem: item]];

if ([item isKindOfClass: [NSString class]])
    return [[[ShadowTextCell alloc] initTextCell: [cell stringValue]] autorelease];
return cell;
```